# Problems with spectral decompositon of a $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

Given a matrix $M$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3,\lambda_4$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $|v1\rangle,|v2\rangle,|v3\rangle,|v4\rangle$. One can write

$ M = \lambda_1 |v1\rangle\langle v1| + \lambda_2 |v2\rangle\langle v2| + \lambda_3 |v3\rangle\langle v3| + \lambda_4 |v4\rangle\langle v4| $.

For the matrix $M$ below, $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 =0$, however, $\lambda_3 |v3\rangle\langle v3| + \lambda_4 |v4\rangle\langle v4| \neq M$.

#### Edit

In the suggested duplicate answer, the problem is with the ordering of eigenvalues. However, in my case, it seems that the problem arises from the syntax used for vectors/matrices, or may be something different?

```
M = 
  {{1/4 (3 + Cos[2 t ω]), 1/4 I Sin[2 t ω], 1/2 I Sin[t ω], Cos[t ω]}, 
   {-(1/4) I Sin[2 t ω], 1/2 Sin[t ω]^2, 0, -(1/2) I Sin[t ω]}, 
   {-(1/2) I Sin[t ω], 0, 1/2 Sin[t ω]^2, -(1/4) I Sin[2 t ω]}, 
   {Cos[t ω], 1/2 I Sin[t ω], 1/4 I Sin[2 t ω], 1/4 (3 + Cos[2 t ω])}};

v3 = ({{-1}, {-I Cot[(t ω)/2]}, {I Cot[(t ω)/2]}, {1}});

v3D = (-{{1, I Cot[(t ω)/2], -I Cot[(t ω)/2], 1}});

v4 = ({{1}, {-I Tan[(t ω)/2]}, {-I Tan[(t ω)/2]}, {1}}); 

v4D = ({{1, I Tan[(t ω)/2], I Tan[(t ω)/2], 1}});

FullSimplify[v3D.v3]
```

> `{{-2 Cot[(t ω)/2]^2}}`

```
FullSimplify[v4D.v4]
```

> `{{2 Sec[(t ω)/2]^2}}`

```
FullSimplify[
 v3D.v3/(-4 Cot[(t ω)/2]^2) + v4D.v4/(4 Sec[(t ω)/2]^2)]
```

> `{{1}}`

```
FullSimplify[
  (1 - Cos[t ω]) v3.v3D/(-4 Cot[(t ω)/2]^2) + 
    (1 + Cos[t ω]) v4.v4D/(2 Sec[(t ω)/2]^2)] // MatrixForm
```

> ```
> MatrixForm[
>   {{(1/32)*(4 + 23*Cos[t*ω] + 4*Cos[2*t*ω] + Cos[3*t*ω])*Sec[(t*ω)/2]^2, 
>     (1/8)*I*(4*Sin[t*ω] + Sin[2*t*ω] - 4*Tan[(t*ω)/2]), 
>     (1/8)*I*(Sin[2*t*ω] + 4*Tan[(t*ω)/2]), 
>     (1/32)*(4 + 23*Cos[t*ω] + 4*Cos[2*t*ω] + Cos[3*t*ω])*Sec[(t*ω)/2]^2},
>    {(-(1/8))*I*(Sin[2*t*ω] + 4*Tan[(t*ω)/2]), 
>     (1/2)*(2 + Cos[t*ω])*Sin[(t*ω)/2]^2, 
>     (1/2)*Cos[t*ω]*Sin[(t*ω)/2]^2, 
>     (-(1/8))*I*(Sin[2*t*ω] + 4*Tan[(t*ω)/2])}, 
>    {(-(1/8))*I*(4*Sin[t*ω] + Sin[2*t*ω] - 4*Tan[(t*ω)/2]), 
>     (1/2)*Cos[t*ω]*Sin[(t*ω)/2]^2, 
>     (1/2)*(2 + Cos[t*ω])*Sin[(t*ω)/2]^2, 
>     (-(1/8))*I*(4*Sin[t*ω] + Sin[2*t*ω] - 4*Tan[(t*ω)/2])},
>    {(1/32)*(16 + 7*Cos[t*ω] + 8*Cos[2*t*ω] + Cos[3*t*ω])* Sec[(t*ω)/2]^2,
>     (1/8)*I*(Sin[2*t*ω] + 4*Tan[(t*ω)/2]),
>     (1/8)*I*(4*Sin[t*ω] + Sin[2*t*ω] - 4*Tan[(t*ω)/2]), 
>     (1/32)*(16 + 7*Cos[t*ω] + 8*Cos[2*t*ω] + Cos[3*t*ω])*Sec[(t*ω)/2]^2}}]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Since the dot product of two vectors should be a scalar, you should probably write in the normal Mathematica way. For example:

```
v3 = {-1, -I Cot[(t ω)/2], I Cot[(t ω)/2], 1};
v3D = -{1, I Cot[(t ω)/2], -I Cot[(t ω)/2], 1};
v3D.v3
```

> `-2 Cot[(t ω)/2]^2`

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica does not attempt to normalise symbolic eigenvectors.  You assume that they  are normalised.

I assume that your variables are real, so specify this as an assumption

```
$Assumptions = {{t, ω} ∈ Reals};
```

Your matrix

```
M = {{1/4 (3 + Cos[2 t ω]), 1/4 I Sin[2 t ω], 
    1/2 I Sin[t ω], 
    Cos[t ω]}, {-(1/4) I Sin[2 t ω], 
    1/2 Sin[t ω]^2, 
    0, -(1/2) I Sin[t ω]}, {-(1/2) I Sin[t ω], 0, 
    1/2 Sin[t ω]^2, -(1/4) I Sin[2 t ω]}, {Cos[
     t ω], 1/2 I Sin[t ω], 1/4 I Sin[2 t ω], 
    1/4 (3 + Cos[2 t ω])}};
```

with eigenvalues and eigenvectors

```
val = Eigenvalues[M]
(* {0, 0, 1 - Cos[t ω], 1 + Cos[t ω]} *)

vec = Eigenvectors[M] // FullSimplify
(* {{-Cos[t ω], I Sin[t ω], 0, 
  1}, {-I Sin[t ω], Cos[t ω], 1, 
  0}, {-1, -I Cot[(t ω)/2], I Cot[(t ω)/2], 
  1}, {1, -I Tan[(t ω)/2], -I Tan[(t ω)/2], 1}} *)
```

Verify that we understand Mathematica's convention for eigenanalysis

```
M.vec[[3]] - val[[3]] vec[[3]] // Simplify
(* {0, 0, 0, 0} *)

M.vec[[4]] - val[[4]] vec[[4]] // Simplify
(* {0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Compute the normalising constants

```
c3 = Conjugate[vec[[3]]].vec[[3]] // FullSimplify
(* 2 Csc[(t ω)/2]^2 *)

c4 = Conjugate[vec[[4]]].vec[[4]] // FullSimplify
(* 2 Sec[(t ω)/2]^2 *)
```

Find two rank 1 matrices (with appropriate scaling)

```
o3 = 
 val[[3]] Outer[Times, vec[[3]], Conjugate[vec[[3]]]]/c3 // 
  FullSimplify
(* {{Sin[(t ω)/
   2]^4, -(1/2) I Sin[(t ω)/2]^2 Sin[t ω], 
  1/2 I Sin[(t ω)/2]^2 Sin[t ω], -Sin[(t ω)/
    2]^4}, {1/2 I Sin[(t ω)/2]^2 Sin[t ω], 
  1/4 Sin[t ω]^2, -(1/4) Sin[t ω]^2, -(1/2) I Sin[(
    t ω)/2]^2 Sin[t ω]}, {-(1/2) I Sin[(t ω)/
    2]^2 Sin[t ω], -(1/4) Sin[t ω]^2, 
  1/4 Sin[t ω]^2, 
  1/2 I Sin[(t ω)/2]^2 Sin[t ω]}, {-Sin[(t ω)/
    2]^4, 1/2 I Sin[(t ω)/2]^2 Sin[t ω], -(1/2) I Sin[(
    t ω)/2]^2 Sin[t ω], Sin[(t ω)/2]^4}} *)

o4 = 
 val[[4]] Outer[Times, vec[[4]], Conjugate[vec[[4]]]]/c4 // 
  FullSimplify
(* {{Cos[(t ω)/2]^4, 
  1/8 I (2 Sin[t ω] + Sin[2 t ω]), 
  1/8 I (2 Sin[t ω] + Sin[2 t ω]), 
  Cos[(t ω)/
   2]^4}, {-(1/8) I (2 Sin[t ω] + Sin[2 t ω]), 
  1/4 Sin[t ω]^2, 
  1/4 Sin[t ω]^2, -(1/8)
     I (2 Sin[t ω] + Sin[2 t ω])}, {-(1/8)
     I (2 Sin[t ω] + Sin[2 t ω]), 1/4 Sin[t ω]^2,
   1/4 Sin[t ω]^2, -(1/8)
     I (2 Sin[t ω] + Sin[2 t ω])}, {Cos[(t ω)/
   2]^4, 1/8 I (2 Sin[t ω] + Sin[2 t ω]), 
  1/8 I (2 Sin[t ω] + Sin[2 t ω]), 
  Cos[(t ω)/2]^4}} *)
```

And see that they sum to give the rank 2 matrix you specified

```
o3 + o4 - M // FullSimplify
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```